# convert floats into unsigned ints c++

Tags: c++, integer

How can I convert or scale floating point numbers into unsigned ints.

I have a floating point vector whose min and max are known, let's say -10 to +10 and I want convert these into unsigned integers from 0 to int_max.

Comment: what do you want to happen if your float value is `-5` ?

Comment: Hi, I want it scaled in the range of 0 to int_max.

Comment: @w.b. Read the question again please

Comment: This is a basic mathematics question. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply calculate where exactly in the float interval the float value is (as a 0-1 value; you can also think of it as percent). Then scale the max integer value accordingly. In code:

```
const float minFloat = -10.f;
const float maxFloat = 10.f;
const unsigned int maxInt = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // Is that what you wanted?

unsigned int convert(float val)
{
  val = (val - minFloat) / (maxFloat - minFloat);
  return static_cast<unsigned int>(std::round(val * maxInt));
}
```